# Python Pandas multiple filtering conditions

Tags: python, pandas

Why does the first method with `&` give me an empty dataframe, while the second with `*` gives me the correct one-line dataframe?

```
id = ["a","b","c"]
product = ["c","b","d"]
id2 = ["a", "b","z"]
type =["sdca","image","wda"]

df2[df2['id'].isin(df1['id']) * df2['type']=='image']
Out[52]: 
  id   type
1  b  image
df2[df2['id'].isin(df1['id']) & df2['type']=='image']    
Out[53]: 
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [id, type]
Index: []
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try. adding brackets -

```
df2[(df2['id'].isin(df1['id'])) & (df2['type']=='image')]
```

Comment: so i should always add brackets between multiple conditions?

Comment: Yes, otherwise it would treat it as bitwise Operators

Comment: If you refer to `df2[df2['id'].isin(df1['id']) * df2['type']=='image']` I never saw someone using this syntax in pandas